# sending a parameters from service to activity by intent

Tags: android, android-activity, intentservice, start-activity, extra

how to send a data from service to activity?

when the service is need to open a specific activity **from background** or even a new instance if this activity is not still at the background (**killed**).

**the question is:**

**so, how do i open this activity (form what user doing whith phone, and instead received the parameters?**

**service:**

```
public void sendDataToActivity(int dialog) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent .putExtra("dialogToUser", dialog);
        getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent); 
}
```

**Main-Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

   //Get Extras and run NumAlert(operation)
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras.containsKey("dialogToUser") ) {
   int operation = extras.getInt("dialogToUser");
       NumAlert ( operation );
   }
}
```

it's not working for me, what's wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom BroadcastReceiver to send data back from service , Here is tutorial [link](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)

Or If you want to call the Service from your Activity, what you want is a bound service. It will bind your service to a variable, and you will be able to use that in the Activity.

Comment: i understand what you wrote, and i try it, but there is a problem with that, because the service running all time even the activity close. and than the receiver will not work